# Error returning boolean in java

Tags: java

I'm trying to do an exercise but a got stuck.

This class will ask the user is he still wants to play with answer yes or no and return a `boolean`.

```
public boolean playAgain() {
    char va;
    boolean t = true;
    boolean ry;
    while (t = true) {
        IO.outputln("Want to play again? (y/n)");
        va = IO.inputCharacter();
        if ((va == 'y') || (va == 'Y')) {
            ry = true;
            t = false;
        } else if ((va == 'n') || (va == 'N')) {
            ry = false;
            t = false;
        }

    }
    return ry;
```

It gives me the next error:

```
[ERROR] variable ry might not have been initialized.
```

Is possible to assign the variable `ry` no result from the beginning? (Because it is going to be assigned in the while loop in any case)

Comment: Because you are setting `ry` in a different scope than it is being declared and returned. Also, you might get some trouble with `while (t = true)`.

Comment: I don't know if those are the names you are using in reality, but I'd suggest you to use more *descriptive* names of variables.

Comment: What value will `ry` have if the user enters "x"?

Comment: Please [search for error messages](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=variable+might+not+have+been+initialized) - pick one of the many duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I changed your code and added some explanations:

```
public boolean playAgain() {    
    char va;
    // you don't need other variables

    while (true) { // infinite loop ... will only stop if user enters "y" or "n"
                   // you should consider avoiding this loop and take every non "yes" answer as a "no" answer.
        IO.outputln("Want to play again? (y/n)");
        va = IO.inputCharacter();

        if ((va=='y') || (va=='Y')) {
            return true; // instantly return the answer ... no need to stop the loop first
        }
        else if ((va=='n')||(va=='N')) {
            return false; // see above ... instantly return the answer
        }    
    }
}
```

Without the loop (every answer that is not "y" or "Y" will be treated as a "no" answer):

```
public boolean playAgain() {    

    IO.outputln("Want to play again? (y/n)");
    char va = IO.inputCharacter();

    if ((va=='y') || (va=='Y')) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Don't get me wrong, I like your solution, but it didn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 3):

You don't assign anything to your variable before you enter another scope.  To better illustrate this point, here is your code with cleaner indentation:

```
public boolean playAgain() {
    char va;
    boolean t = true;
    boolean ry;
    while(t = true) {
        IO.outputln("Want to play again? (y/n)");
        va = IO.inputCharacter();
        if((va == 'y') || (va == 'Y')) {
            ry = true;
            t = false;
        } else if((va == 'n') || (va == 'N')) {
            ry = false;
            t = false;
        }

    }
    return ry;
}
```

You only declare `ry`, but don't initialize it to anything; its initialization is dependent on something inside an `if` statement, which is itself inside of a `while` loop.

When Java compiles something like this, it takes branches into account as well, namely, "Will I go down this if branch?", or, "What happens if this loop never fires?"

Look at your code in this way:

```
public boolean playAgain() {
    char va;
    boolean t = true;
    boolean ry;

    return ry;
}
```

This is the effective removal of the loop, in the case it "never fires".  Notice that we're now returning a variable in which we haven't initialized to anything.  This is unacceptable, so you get a compilation error, "variable `ry` may not have been initialized."

It's assuming that the loop may never fire (although in this case, it's trivially true; you may want to change that to `while(t == true)` or even `while(t)`), and it sees that `ry` is being used later in the method, but doesn't have a value.

You **must** initialize your variable `ry` to a value (e.g. `boolean ry = false`).

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop: `while(t = true)`.  The expression `t = true` returns the value assigned to `t` (which is *always* `true`).  So I'm assuming you actually meant `while(t == true)`--which is redundant.  You give `while` a boolean (which `==` will return for various primitive types and pointers), so you should *never* test whether a boolean is `true` or `false`--just pass the variable, e.g. `while(t)` (or if you want the negation of the variable `while(!t)`).

Second, if the while loop is never entered then `ry` will never be assigned a value--this is why the compiler is complaining.  You, me, and everyone else knows that `t` is initially true therefore the while loop is *definitely* entered but the compiler does *not*.  The simple solution is to:

1. Fix the while loop: `while(t)`
2. Assign an initial value to `ry`--it doesn't matter what, so either `boolean ry = false` or `boolean ry = true` will work.

Here is an example that shows why testing a boolean for `true` or `false` doesn't make sense.  Does the following make sense?

```
public static boolean isUpperCase(final char c){
    if( ((c < 'A') == true) || ((c > 'Z') == true) )
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Hopefully it's clear that this is ridiculous code.  First, we are testing whether a boolean expression is `true` or `false` and second we are returning the evaluation of that.  Without changing the test, an immediately better way would be:

```
public static boolean isUpperCase(final char c){
    return !( (c < 'A') || (c > 'Z') );
}
```

Using De Morgan's laws, a slightly cleaner way could be used:

```
public static boolean isUpperCase(final char c){
    return c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z';
}
```

p.s. As per Tom's answer, the fact that it doesn't matter what value you initially assign `ry` (yet the compiler requires it) suggests that there is a better way to code this.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign false, or you can use Boolean (instead of boolean) and assign null at the beginning.